# Getting content from search box finding it in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this is a broad question, but seriously.. I really couldnt find and answer for this, only the `LIKE` keyword that checks if it contains it..

I want to look for something in a db if it contains it, starts with it, or ends with it and by order by the most populaur result?

I have a search box in bootstrap and when the content is changed, an ajax request is sent for the new content..

It there a way to do this.

Comment: `in a db if it contains it` ... would that be anywhere, any table, any column, but seriously

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE is nothing. Use *full text search* in mysql. There are disadvantages: myisam required, for char/varchar/text fields only. See more info here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

A great alternative is using a real search engine such as Elasticsearch, built on the top of Apache Lucene: fast, relevant, flexible, adaptable, works with json api. See more info here: https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Comment: InnoDB supports FULLTEXT search in 5.6+: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Comment: I too would steer away from full text search like the plague. It was put in for marketing reasons, and for the meek.